# plotting sub-figures with borders in latex

Tags: subfloats, border

I'm running the below code to plot three figures, however, the border between the two figures creates two lines in parallel and I want only one line to be in the middle of the two figures for a better appearance .. is there a way to do it.

P.S. I'm submitting for IEEE

```
\documentclass[journal,draftcls,onecolumn,12pt,twoside]{IEEEtranTCOM}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfon
t=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfi g}
\fi 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.967\linewidth]{J_Fig6}}
            \label{1b}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.967\linewidth]{S3}}
            \label{1c}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{ a. blala  b.  blala c. blala }
        \label{fig:5}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. The code should compile. Finally, you can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: try `\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}...\end{subfigure}\hskip1pt\begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}`

Comment: I updated the code. I need the border between the two figures to be one line only instead of two lines

Comment: BTW, subfig uses subfloat, not subfigure.  OTOH, I used IEEEtran[comsoc] instead of IEEEtramsTCOM (which I couldn't find).

Comment: @Diana, see my answer below. i explain why you have two vertical lines between images and how to merge then into one (actually tight them together).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solve with the comments.